# problem with extracting .tgz file

Tags: tar

I downloaded a big data file (others.tgz, some 30GB) from an ftp site. 
I did

```
tar -zxvf others.tgz
```

some files were extracted ( four files, where it is supposed to have 6 files ) after that it came out throwing the error,

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: "Unexpected EOF" means that the tarball isn't complete, or is corrupt.  You'll have to redownload.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the file did not download correctly. You can check if the file sizes match. Even better, if the site provides one, you can check if the hashes match.

Unfortunately you will likely need to re-download the file.

Comment: I re-downloaded it and extracted. Same problem. What are these "hashes" to match.

Comment: Some sites publish a the hash (usually MD5) of a file along with the download so you can easily check if the downloaded file matches the provided one.

Comment: If downloading a second time didn't work, there is also the possibility that the original file has a problem.

Comment: They did't have any such files. They provided the original data on our request. As you said, it seems original file is corrupted. We shall request them to prepare fresh archive and upload again.